# Могут ли в русском языке озвончаться Х, Ц, Ч, Щ или это невозможно?

Tags: фонетика

Однажды я на одном сайте, давая ответ, написал, что буква Х в русском языке изредка может озвончаться — передавать звонкий согласный звук. В принципе важен звук, а не фонема (о фонеме я и не писал вовсе). А мне в ответном комментарии указали, что я допустил ошибку, причём ещё и грубую.

Я согласен, что буква Х передаёт в основном глухой звук, твёрдый либо мягкий. Да и в учебниках пишут, что Х, Ц, Ч, Щ всегда непарные глухие. Однако обратите внимание вот на что: мы же говорим не фу[т]бол, [с]дача, во[к]зал, а фу[д]бол, [з]дача, во[г]зал. Шумные озвончаются перед звонкими шумными.

Итак, могут ли Х, Ц, Ч, Щ быть звонкими, или они глухие, и дело с концом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Парным для глухого [х] будет звонкий [γ] (он того же места и способа образования), встречающийся в таких словах, как бу**хг**алтер, а**г**а, **Г**осподь (в церковной традиции произносится с фрикативным согласным в начале), в выделенных местах.

Считается, что [ц] и [ч] — аффрикаты, и их артикуляция состоит из последовательного слитного произнесения звукосочетаний [тс] и [т’ш’] соответственно. Следовательно, для нахождения звонких пар этих звуков в речи следует подобрать контексты типа *кавказе**ц д**умал* [дзд] и *мя**ч б**росил* [д'ж'б].

Пример озвонченного [ш'] (щ на письме) находим в том же *мя**ч б**росил* [д'**ж'**б].

Нет никаких фонетических ограничений для существования звонких пар упомянутых вами звуков в современном русском литературном языке. Другое дело, что это именно звуки, которые можно услышать во время живого разговора; фонемами они не являются, и в этом смысле отдельных таких звонких фонем в русском языке нет.

Answer (score 4):

**"Ч"** озвончается (передаёт звук [д'ж']) перед буквой парного звонкого согласного.

Примеры: *алчба́, Кучбо́рская.*

**"Ц"**  озвончается (передаёт звук [дз]) перед буквами звонких согласных, кроме сонорных и "в". Сочетание встречается в отдельных иностранных собственных именах.

Примеры: *Ги́нцбург, Лао Цзы.*

(По книге Аванесова *"Русское литературное произношение"*)